# How do I convert an existing static HTML website to Joomla?

Tags: html, joomla

I have a huge problem with converting my pre-existing HTML based webpage into Joomla.
I have tried for the last 36hours to figure out how this Cms works, and it all seems to be a waste of time. I wonder if there is any quicker solution in my case? Or do I have to adapt my entire content and rewrite big chunks of code? It doesnt seem to be any easy way to just add the HTML i have and just work with what i already have. I am really content with my webpage as it is, all I want is to publish it and enable some login panel for admins and lower level admins...

Some guidance here thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn off the editor (edit your profile and set editor to none) and then create an article for each html page by just pasting in the html (but not the head or the body tags).

Have you looked at the beginner materials?
http://docs.joomla.org/Beginners